# SSIS set variable value from ODBC query result

Tags: ssis, postgresql-9.5

In my SSIS package, I am using `Execute SQL Task` to get a ID from ODBC (PostgreSQL) query and set the value to a variable

Here is the query. It will be replaced with select Id from activity Table

```
SELECT  floor(random() * 10 + 1)::int as Id;
```

Whenever I execute it I get following error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to
> variable "var_activity_id": "Value does not fall within the expected
> range.".

[image]
[image]

Same approach for OLE DB data source works fine. But it fails with ODBC. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the resultname to `1` for ODBC connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add this for the record.  With ODBC connections in ssis, ResultNames should not use the columns names but a 1- based increment.  1 for the first column, 2 for the second column...

Names or 0 based incrementing will result in this error message:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range
```